# I want to upload two files using two file input in the same form in laravel

Tags: laravel, file, file-upload

I want to create a simple completion entry form. The entries are supposed to have fields for users profile picture and the documents itself. I dont want to put it in an array [] I just want to upload the picture and document separately. How do I process this in laravel?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just do:

```
$picture = $request->file('picture');
$document = $request->file('document');
```

More info https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests#files

Answer (score 0):

Front:

```
<form method="POST" action="yourroute" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input class="form-control" type="file" name="image">
    <input class="form-control" type="file" name="document">
</form>
```

On backend

```
public function upload(Request $request) {
    $image = $request->file('image');
    $document = $request->file('document');
}
```

hope it helps!

Comment: Does this send the file name to the database or does it also send the actual file to the specified location. I'd try it and get back to you

Comment: No with this u get hashed file. Then u can use move function for placing image where u need. 
I use Lib called http://image.intervention.io/. Great lib will help you a lot and you have examples on their site also. :))

Answer (score 0):

Change your code in controller:

Here I use public/images directory for image upload and 
public/documents directory for documents upload you can replace with your folder path

```
public function upload(Request $request) {
    if($request->image != ''){
        $path = 'images/';
        $file = $request->image;
        $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move($path, $filename);
    }
    if($request->document != ''){
        $path = 'documents/';
        $file = $request->documents;
        $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move($path, $filename);
    }
}
```